How to Mockk an extension function on a mockked constructor call
The following is a slight variation on the example from the Mockk docs for mocking a top-level extension function:
data class Obj(val value: Int)
fun Obj.extensionFunc() = value + 5

@Test
fun mockks() {
    mockkStatic(Obj::extensionFunc)
    mockkConstructor(Obj::class)

    every {
        anyConstructed<Obj>().extensionFunc()
    } returns 11

    assertEquals(11, Obj(5).extensionFunc())

    verify {
        Obj(5).extensionFunc()
    }
}

The key difference in this case is that instead of specifying an explicit instance (Obj(5)) in the every block, I'm mocking the constructor as well, and specifying anyConstructed instance. This setup results in both the real constructor & real extension function being invoked, leading to an assertion error since Obj(5).extensionFunc() returns the calculated value (10) instead of mockked value (11).
This setup does seem to work as expected when either the constructor is not mocked, or when the function is a proper method on the Obj class, rather than an extension function. It's just when combining both types of mocks (constructor + extension) where I can't figure out how to make go.
Is this a supported feature of Mockk? Is there something I'm missing about how to make this work?  I really appreciate any help.

Why do you have to mock the constructor too? Just every { any<Obj>().extensionFunc() } returns 11 will suffice.

Ah! that's it!  Thx for the suggestion :)
